# How to change tileSize in XYZ from default([256,256]) to something else for openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, openstreetmap, xyz, xyz-tiles

I am trying to change the tile size and I have not been able. Below is the code.

```
var projection = get('EPSG:4326');
local_url = 'assets/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        url: this.local_url,
        projection: projection,
        wrapX: false,
        tileSize: [1024,1024]
      })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0,0],
    zoom:0,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 5,
    projection: projection
  })
});
```

No matter what I set the `tileSize` to be it is always `[256,256]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are serving tiles from a local URL via:

```
 local_url = 'assets/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
```

and if those PNGs are 256x256 then that's what you'll get regardless of what you try and ask for. Are they?

The `tileSize` will only be honoured if the server is capable of delivering tiles of that

Comment: The files are not 256x256, it is more than that.\

Comment: The file size is 1900x1268

Comment: Which file is that size? You should have a set of PNG tile files in `assets/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` Are all of them 1900x1268?

Comment: Yes, I know. For now I am only focused on file in 0/0/0.png. This is the file with 1900x1268 size

Comment: Why are you trying to change `tileSize`? Your tile size is 1900x1268, which is kind of large but. Are you seeing this large tile on your map?